# RxJs: http.get is getting an array, but I want the subscriber to get individual elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am writing an Angular2 app (RC5) which uses a NodeJS backend RESTful API.

One of the backend routes returns an array of 'Candidates':

```
exports.list = function (req, res, next) {
  const sort = req.query.sort || null
  const fields = req.query.fields || null

  let query = Candidate.find()

  if (sort !== null) {
    query.sort(sort.replace(',', ' '))
  }

  if (fields !== null) {
    query.select(Candidate.reduceFields(fields))
  }

  query
    .then(function (candidates) {
      res.send(candidates)
    })
    .catch(next)
}
```

I am receiving this in the frontend in a service:

```
  getCandidates() {
    return this.http
      .get(`http://localhost:3500/api/v1/proboard/candidates`)
      .map(function (res) {
         console.log("First:" + res.json());
         return res.json();
      })
   };
```

My controller then subscribes to this observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.candidateService.getCandidates()
      .subscribe(
        (candidates: Candidate[]) => {
          console.debug("Got:" + JSON.stringify(candidates));
          this.candidates = candidates;
         }
      );
  }
```

This is working, but not the way I expected (or wanted?).  The controller gets an array of objects from the stream, not individual elements of the array.

So for example, if there were 20 candidates returned from the backend, the controller would log that the subscription code was called once, and it would recieve an array of 20 elements.

What I wanted was the controller's subscription code to be called 20 times, each time with a single element, not an array of 1 element.

I'm missing something in terms of my understanding of how RxJs works.  How should I refactor this code so that the conroller gets one element at a time instead of the whole array at once?

My motivation for wanting this is because I want, ultimately, to not just recieve the candidate list as it is now, but any changes to the list while the controller is active.

Comment: Downvoters:  I'm happy to improve my question.  All I ask is that you point out what edits you would like to see.

Comment: Hey John, it has been a couple of weeks and you never gave feedback about the answers or selected one of them. If you used one of them to fix your problem, please select and upvote. If they didn't work, please tell us why so we (who answered) can also learn from this issue.

Comment: @BeetleJuice: Fear not.  I simply haven't yet had an opportunity to work through this completely yet.  Shortly after I posted this, everything kind of went sideways and I haven't had the time I expected to for this.

Comment: @BeetleJuice: As promised, I have come back to this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a very similar requirement in my app.

Change:

```
this.subscription = this.candidateService.getCandidates()
                        .subscribe(...);
```

To

```
this.subscription = this.candidateService.getCandidates()
                        .switchMap(candidates => Observable.from(candidates))
                        .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Good sugestion.  But, to clarify, would my controller code be called one, or 20 times?

Comment: @JohnDibling Everything up to `.subscribe` is called once, but its first argument (the callback where you decide what to do with the next candidate) will be executed 20 times.

Answer (score 1):

Your back-end is sending an array of data and therefore your front-end observable is emitting the same array.

If you want your front-end observable to emit individual elements of the array, you need to create it using appropriate operators instead of just using `map` operator. Check the [from](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md) operator.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.  In reading that documentation, it's kind of amazing that you were able to figure this out in the first place.